# How to Validate After Blur Event Function?

Tags: angular

Angular react form, "title" must have minimum of 4 characters without leading and trailing whitespace. Added validator and auto-trim-out leading and trailing spaces on `blur`, but validator won't accept the trimmed string. For example,  `12345`  becomes `12345` is still invalid. Note, `vcontrol.value` is read-only, can't combine trim and assign into custom function.

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<input type="text" formControlName="title" (blur)="leaving($event)" placeholder="Input title, minimum 4 char.">
```

```js
this.myForm = this.formbuilder.group(
{
    title: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, this.NeedTrim, Validators.minLength(4)])
});
    
public NeedTrim(vcontrol: FormControl) 
{
    const SameLengthAfterTrim = (vcontrol.value || '').trim().length === (vcontrol.value || '').length;  // control.value is READ-Only, can't apply trim() assign here.
    // this line cause "message:"Maximum call stack size exceeded"
    // stack:"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"
    // vcontrol.setValue(vcontrol.value.toString().trim());
    return SameLengthAfterTrim ? null : { 'MustTrim': true };
}

leaving(v: any)
{
    v.target.value = v.target.value.toString().trim();  // auto-trim out leading and trailing.
}
```

Comment: How about setValue on the control..?

Comment: @MikeOne good point, adding `vcontrol.setValue(vcontrol.value.toString().trim());` into `NeedTrim()` and before `return`, got **message:"Maximum call stack size exceeded"
stack:"RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**

Comment: Yeah.. that’s be because your validators run again. You can add { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false } as an options object to setValue

Comment: @MikeOne Same, but appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry man. Another idea - don’t try the trim in the control, just trim it when you are sending the form data..? It’s not a validator task to change input anyway? Just a suggestion..

Comment: @MikeOne No worries. Developers just keep trying, right? :)   I'm doing `if (this.myForm.invalid)` in form submit so I'm out of luck.

Comment: @MikeOne `setValue()` works, basically my `NeedTrim()` is the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger validation after modifying the value, update the `formControl` value, not the raw html input:

```js
  leaving(v: any) {
    const titleField = this.myForm.controls.title;
    const trimmed = titleField.value.trim();  
    titleField.setValue(trimmed);
  }
```

> (*after adding .setValue() inside validator*) got message:"Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Don't put the update logic inside the validator; it needs to be separate.  Just call it on blur.

Then, make your validator function evaluate based on the trimmed length:

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<input type="text" formControlName="title" (blur)="trimWhitespace()">
```

```js
  myForm = this.formbuilder.group({
    title: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, trimmedMinLength(4)])
  });

  trimWhitespace() {
    const titleField = this.myForm.controls.title;
    const trimmed = titleField.value.trim();  
    titleField.setValue(trimmed);
  }
```

```js
function trimmedMinLength(minLength: number) {
  return (control: FormControl) => {
    const userInput = control.value || '';
    
    return userInput.trim().length < minLength
      ? { 'minLength': true }
      : null;
  };
}
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-68928365-enxtni?devtoolsheight=60&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Awesome! Basically my `NeedTrim()` function inside validation array screws things up. Thank you.